# CURL - How to pass username and password for OATH2 Ping-federate authentication?

Tags: node.js, authentication, curl, pingfederate

I have a working URL that goes to Pingfederate and ask for user/pass.

Upon entering - it gives me Authorization code. URL is:

https://PINGURL.com/as/authorization.oauth2?client_id=MyClientID&redirect_uri=MyURL&scope=openid%20profile&response_type=code

How to send user/pass by using CURL and above URL so that do not need to enter it manually?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

For authorization code flow, there's no such parameters available - the user will be prompted to authenticate. If they already have a session, then it might be transparent to the user.

If you really want to pass in the username/password, you may want to consider another OAuth grant type, like resource owner password credentials.

More information on what's possible is covered on our developer site here: https://www.pingidentity.com/content/developer/en/resources/oauth-2-0-developers-guide.html